# android persistence activity which never stop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i need a activity which permanently receive data from a service. This activity should never stop, because it saves the received data in a database. Even when the activity is in background it needs to save the received data and do some other things. Is this possible?

Comment: there is no such thing as an activity that runs in the background

Comment: it is not an activity you need. it is a service.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the functionality that saves the received data in the database into a service. Then it will always run, also in the background.

Comment: Do a Bound Service stop when the activity stops?

Comment: Yes, "A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it.". [Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Android service for this. 
Other way is to use a method in that service which listens to the database and perform your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but forgot the idea to use an activity (when an activity is in background it is destroyed, then rebuild if you relaunch your application). You could use an Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

if it would be an activity, you need to have it open all the time. which has no practical relevance. So i would rather build my own service for the client to handle that traffic in background.